# JQuery initiate function on document ready and resize

Tags: jquery, window-resize, document-ready

I am trying to get a menu to slide in and out from the left hand side when an icon is clicked.  I get this working without issue, however I need to have the menu behave slightly different depending on the browser size.  I therefore need to know the browser width on document ready and on resize. I cant seem to get this working well at all, it either doesn't activate the correct 'onclick' function according to screen size or it activates multiple times.  I have tried many different variations of the below.  Can any one please assist.  I have created a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cDppA/42/  initiate

```
 var menuInitialized = false;

function doMenu() {
    var width = $(window).width(); 

    if (width < 550) {

         if (!menuInitialized) {
              $('.icon-menu-2').on('click', function (event) { 
            console.log('small');
               });     
            menuInitialized = true;
         }
    } else if ((width < 800) && (width > 550)) {
        if (menuInitialized) {
             $('.icon-menu-2').on('click', function (event) { 
            console.log('large');
              });     
            menuInitialized = false;
        }
    }

}
$(document).ready(doMenu);
$(window).resize(doMenu);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you use `.on('click', function(){})`, you **add** a binding to the click event, not just replacing it as I assume you expected. So what ends up happening is that it's called several time on clicking. You can resolve this be unbinding the click event before binding again, using `$('.icon-menu').unbind('click');`.  I've only modified line 5 on your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/asifrc/cDppA/43/)

Additionally, my screen is larger than 800px, so if I click when my screen is maximized, nothing happens since neither of your if conditions cover >800 .

Let me know if it works or if you have any questions :)

Comment: that works, can't believe its such a simple solution - thanks!  I don't need it to work for anything above 800px as a static menu will be displayed.